# Segmentation Fault With Multiple Threads

Tags: multithreading, multiprocess

I get error segmentation fault because of the free() at the end of this equation...

don't I have to free the temporary variable *stck?  Or since it's a local pointer and 
was never assigned a memory space via malloc, the compiler cleans it up for me?

```
void * push(void * _stck)
{

  stack * stck = (stack*)_stck;//temp stack
  int task_per_thread = 0; //number of push per thread


  pthread_mutex_lock(stck->mutex);
  while(stck->head == MAX_STACK -1 )
  {
    pthread_cond_wait(stck->has_space,stck->mutex);
  }

  while(task_per_thread <= (MAX_STACK/MAX_THREADS)&&
        (stck->head < MAX_STACK) &&
    (stck->item < MAX_STACK)//this is the amount of pushes
                //we want to execute
       )
  { //store actual value into stack
    stck->list[stck->head]=stck->item+1;
    stck->head = stck->head + 1;
    stck->item = stck->item + 1; 
    task_per_thread = task_per_thread+1; 
  }

  pthread_mutex_unlock(stck->mutex);


  pthread_cond_signal(stck->has_element);


  free(stck);


  return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: You totally changed the question so my old answer doesn't really make sense anymore. I'll try to answer the new one (old answer still below) but for reference, next time please just ask a new question instead of changing an old one.

`stck` is a pointer that you set to point to the same memory as `_stck` points to. A pointer does not imply allocating memory, it just points to memory that is already (hopefully) allocated. When you do for example

```
char* a = malloc(10);  // Allocate memory and save the pointer in a.
char* b = a;           // Just make b point to the same memory block too.
free(a);               // Free the malloc'd memory block.
free(b);               // Free the same memory block again.
```

you free the *same memory* twice.

-- old answer

In push, you're setting `stck` to point to the *same memory block as `_stck`*, and at the end of the call you free stack (thereby calling free() on your common stack once from each thread)

Remove the `free()` call and, at least for me, it does not crash anymore. Deallocating the stack should probably be done in `main()` after joining all the threads.

Comment: you are right....my free was messing up my run time...but I still have other issues....I still get error after removing free()

Comment: @user852415 Answered your new question too... if it helps you, please mark as answered and ans a new one instead of changing this one again.